# 'User' object has no attribute 'leave'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am making a leave application module and I got "User has no attribute" errors

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User;  
    from django.db.models.signals import post_save
    from django.dispatch import receiver
    LEAVE_CHIOCE = (
    ('casual', 'Casual Leave'),
    ('vacation', 'Vacation Leave'),
    ('commuted', 'Commuted Leave'),
    ('special_casual', 'Special Casual Leave'),
    ('restricted', 'Restricted Leave'),
    ('st

ation', 'Station Leave'),
    )

    APPLICATION_STATUSES = (

    ('accepted', 'Accepted'),
    ('rejected', 'Rejected'),
    ('processing', 'Being Processed')

    )
    class Leave(models.Model):
       user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='applied_for', on_delete=models.CASCADE);
       leave_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LEAVE_CHIOCE);
       applied_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True);
       start_date = models.DateField();
       end_date = models.DateField();
       purpose = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True);
       leave_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True);
       processing_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=APPLICATION_STATUSES);

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
       if created:
          Leave.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.leave.save()
```

forms.py

```
 from django import forms;
 from  . models import Leave, ApplicationRequest, RemainingLeaves;
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User;
 from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm;
 from datetime import datetime


 class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model =  User;
      fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email');

 class LeaveForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Leave;
    class Meta:
       fields = ( 'leave_type', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'purpose', 'leave_address');
```

view.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse;
from . models import Leave, ApplicationRequest, RemainingLeaves;
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required;
from . forms import LeaveForm, UserForm;
from django.db import transaction
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import os;


# Create your views here.
@login_required(login_url='/login')
@transaction.atomic
def getLeaveTemplate(request):
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)));
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user);
        leave_form = LeaveFor[enter image description here][1]m(request.POST, instance=request.user.leave)

        if user_form.is_valid() and leave_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save();
            leave_form.save();
            return HttpResponse("Thanksss");
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user);
        leave_form = LeaveForm(instance=request.user.leave);
    return render(request, BASE_DIR+"/templates/pages/leaveform.html", {'user_form':user_form});
```

Comment: Try changing `request.user.leave` to `request.user.applied_for`. This is what you specified the `related_name` to be in the `OneToOneField`.

Comment: post in the answers section so can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) described in Django documentation:

> The name to use for the relation from the related object back to this one.

You are declaring the `related_name` to be `applied_for` on the following line:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='applied_for', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This means that a `Leave` object will have the property `user` which is used to get the related `User` object. To go from a `User` object to the related `Leave` object the property `[related_name]` is added. This is in your case `applied_for`. To remove your errors simply change each `request.user.leave` to `request.user.applied_for`.

In order to change the `applied_for` property to `leave` you can change the definition to the following:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='leave', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But the `related_name` is an optional argument and it has a useful [default value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield):

> If you do not specify the related_name argument for the OneToOneField, Django will use the lower-case name of the current model as default value.

So in your case not supplying a default value will add the property `leave` to `User` objects

```
# in model
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# in view
request.user.leave
```